# Squid Proxy Server - Port numbers - HTTP - HTTPS etc

Tags: proxy, https, port, squid

I have a virtual proxy client and I have a squid proxy server.

```
root@arch:/etc/squid # cat /etc/squid/acls/ports.acl
80 # http
21 # ftp

root@arch:/etc/squid # cat /etc/squid/acls/sslports.acl
443 # https
3001 # ntop
```

I am curious about port numbers and squid. I know that the port number is not "magic", you can use any port from 1-65535 you like. Ports in the range 1-1023 are "well-known ports" which are assigned worldwide to specific applications or protocols.

But basically, I want to understand that when I change 443 to something else or when I add port numbers like

```
root@arch:/etc/squid # cat /etc/squid/acls/sslports.acl
4888 # https
3001 # ntop
```

What is the matter?  I have a proxy server and another client machine.
I am trying to see these changes on the client machine browser but nothing I can see.
For example:
https://www.example.com:443 works

But I change https
https://www.example.com:4888 , isn't it supposed to work also?

Can you please help me to understand?

Comment: What do you mean by "supposed to work"? Did something fail? What exactly failed? What errors did you receive?

Comment: root@arch:/etc/squid # cat /etc/squid/acls/sslports.acl
4888 # https
3001 # ntop

In this configuration, I was thinking that https websites now has port number 4888
So, if I browse to https://www.example.com:4888, I was expecting to see the normal page. But instead, I got problem loading page.